# How Can I Compile Counts of Bigrams from Several .csv Files into One .csv File using R

Tags: r, csv, statistics, export-to-csv

I have a series of .csv files labeled Trigrams1A, Trigrams1B, ... Trigrams66A, Trigrams66B consisting of the counts of trigrams from a text file. My goal is to compile counts of specific trigrams from each of these files into one table. My thought was to try to create a row with the specific counts in each file and then stack the rows, but it does not seem to be working. A sample code follows:

```
z <- 1
while (z <= 66) {

 document <- paste("Trigrams", z, "B", ".csv", sep="")

 mytable <- read.csv(document, header = T, sep=",")

 a <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="came here from")])    
 b <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="go home with")])   
 c <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="going to split")])     
 d <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="i m gonna")])     
 e <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="a lot of")])     
 f <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="lot of money")])     
 g <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="all the way")])     
 h <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="i m going")])     
 i <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="i promise you")])     
 j <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="i want to")])     
 k <- length(mytable[which(mytable=="i trust you")])

 rows <- c(a,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)

 columns <- rbind(rows)

 z <- z+1
}
```

How can I effectively get the counts from the tables, combine them, and then write this combination into a new table?

Comment: You need to start with an empty data frame and bind the rows to it.  At the moment you are not binding `rows` to anything else!  You might also want to include `z` in the row so that you know which file it comes from.

Comment: Something like this: `library(dplyr); trigram_counts = bind_rows(lapply(list.files(pattern="Trigrams.*.csv"), read.csv, header=TRUE)) %>% group_by(column_name) %>% tally`. Where `column_name` is the name of the column with the trigrams (assuming the column name is the same in all of the files).

Comment: Show the output of `dput(mytable)` from `Trigrams1A.csv` so we can see what each table looks like. Also, show what you want the final output to look like.

Comment: dput(mytable)
structure(list(trigrams = structure(1:23, .Label = c("came here from", 
"don t wanna", "first round i", , "wanna go home", "with nothing the", 
"yeah me too", "you . ."), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("trigrams", "Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))

Comment: The output would be a .csv with columns labeled with each trigram and the counts subsequently below for each observation. Row 2 would therefore have the counts of all trigrams for Trigrams1A, 3 would have counts for 1B etc.